# clangd No client with id 1

Tags: neovim, filetype-c++, mason, clangd

I am running Manjaro KDE and neovim version v0.9.5. I have a slightly modified version of [this nvim config](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch) and I have downloaded the clangd language server. Everything was working fine and great, up until yesterday, where in the middle of editing a file, suddenly clangd stopped working. If I close nvim and reopen any c++ file, I get the error `No client with id 1` and sometimes also `Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0`. However if I open another file, sometimes I get this error, or sometimes it opens fine and suddenly clangd is working without any issue, but if I restart nvim and open any file, it throws me this error once again.

Here is [lsp.log](https://pastebin.com/MTaiirhJ) and here is LspInfo output. [image]

If I run :checkhealth, everything is OK, except mason complainint about languages like GO, PHP, Java, etc not being available, but I am not using those. I am truly confused what to do or what is even wrong, to me it seems like clangd randomly chooses if it should work or not. I have found a temporarily workaround which is to open different files until clangd is working, everytime I start nvim.

Comment: Please [edit] to include text instead of screenshots. This might be something worth filing an issue on the lsp client or clangd page for.